# T-SQL get price between two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, duplicate-data

I am making a small database trading system and I have a problem with duplication which I am unsure how to solve. Basically I have a table with prices with the datetime which that price was set and I also have a table with the time a trade was made. I want to get the correct price based on trade datetime.

```
USE [a_trading_system]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Trade]    Script Date: 06/30/2012 14:49:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trade](
[trade_id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[trade_volume] [int] NOT NULL,
[trade_action] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[trade_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[timestap] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[trader_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[exch_ticker] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Trades] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[trade_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trade]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Trade_Contract] FOREIGN   KEY([exch_ticker])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contract] ([exch_ticker])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trade] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Trade_Contract]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trade]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Trade_Trader] FOREIGN   KEY([trader_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trader] ([trader_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trade] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Trade_Trader]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Trade] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Trades_trade_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [trade_id]
GO



USE [a_trading_system]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Contract]    Script Date: 06/30/2012 14:56:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contract](
[exch_ticker] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[exch_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[portfolio_id] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[region_cd] [varchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Contract] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[exch_ticker] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contract]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contract_portfolio]    FOREIGN KEY([portfolio_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[portfolio] ([portfolio_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contract] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contract_portfolio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contract]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contract_region] FOREIGN   KEY([region_cd])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Region] ([region_cd])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contract] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contract_region]
GO



USE [a_trading_system]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[price_details]    Script Date: 06/30/2012 14:58:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[price_details](
[price_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[exch_ticker] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[price_set_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[buy_price] [decimal](7, 2) NOT NULL,
[sell_price] [decimal](7, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_price_detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[price_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[price_details]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    [FK_price_details_Contract] FOREIGN KEY([exch_ticker])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contract] ([exch_ticker])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[price_details] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_price_details_Contract]
GO
```

**View**

```
USE [a_trading_system]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[V_all_uk]    Script Date: 06/30/2012 14:39:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[V_all_uk]
AS

SELECT distinct
co.exch_ticker,
--co.region_cd, 
po.portfolio_type, 
r.region_name, 
r.currency,
t.trade_id,
t.trade_volume,
t.trade_action,
t.trade_date,
pr.buy_price,

--(select distinct pr.buy_price from price_details pr
--where pr.price_set_date <= t.trade_date or  pr.price_set_date >= t.trade_date) as    price_details,

--MIN(t.trade_date) as trade_date,
--pr.buy_price,
--pr.sell_price,

--pr.price_set_date, --This is the cause of duplication
--pr.price_set_time,case when t.trade_date IS NOT NULL then 

--case 
--when t.trade_action = 'Buy' then 
--t.trade_volume * max(pr.buy_price)
--else
--case when trade_action = 'Sell' then
--t.trade_volume * max(pr.sell_price)
--end 
--end as 'trade_value' ,
tr.trader_name,
tr.trader_address, 
tr.phone
FROM dbo.Contract as co 
INNER JOIN dbo.Portfolio as po ON co.portfolio_id = po.portfolio_id 
INNER JOIN dbo.region as r ON co.region_cd = r.region_cd 
INNER JOIN dbo.Trade as t ON co.exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker 
INNER JOIN dbo.trader as tr ON t.trader_id = tr.trader_id
inner join dbo.price_details as pr on pr.exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker

where r.region_cd = 'UK'

--group by 

--co.exch_ticker,
--co.region_cd, 
--po.portfolio_type, 
--r.region_name, 
--r.currency,
--t.trade_id,
--t.trade_volume,
--t.trade_action,
--pr.buy_price,
--pr.sell_price,
--tr.trader_name,
--tr.trader_address, 
--tr.phone

GO
```

These are the three main tables if you need to see data as well just say because I don't usually post SQL questions on this website.

**Explanation**

If a price is set at 12:20 and the price is 100 then at 12:40 the price is 80. These are two date ranges. So if I buy at 12:30 then I am buying at the price of 100 because that is last price. I am also doing my joins in a view so I can see all data. I will post that now.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my updated post. I have created a view with my database logic but I get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest price prior to a particular trade date:

```
select buy_price, sell_price
  from price_details
  where exch_ticker = @exch_ticker and price_set_date =
    ( select max( price_set_date )
        from price_details
        where exch_ticker = @exch_ticker and price_set_date <= @trade_date )
```

You may want to add an index on `exch_ticker`/`trade_date`(desc) to `price_details`.

Comment: I can see what your doing but how would I apply this to my view?

Comment: Change the view to `JOIN` `price_details` with the extra logic to select an appropriate price and picking up the `exch_ticker` and `trade_date` from `trade as t`.  Quickly.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now could you show me an example? All I want to do is show the correct price based on trade date using the view.

Comment: I did this in the where clause: where r.region_cd = 'UK' and
t.exch_ticker = pr.exch_ticker and
price_set_date = ( 
select MAX(price_set_date) from price_details 
where  price_set_date <= t.trade_date
group by 
price_set_date
) But this prevents the view from running with error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: `inner join dbo.price_details as pr on pr.exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker  and pr.price_set_date = ( select max( price_set_date ) from price_details where exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker and price_set_date <= t.trade_date )` might be close.  Your `group by` clause causes the multiple return values.

Comment: I feel silly it does work but because of my dummy data there is no earlier date. I will look at the other persons solution before I pick this but thanks for your help I have never come across that type of problem before.

Comment: You can use a `left outer join` to get all of your trades with the corresponding prices, if any.  It will return rows that have no corresponding price and supply `NULL` values for the price column(s).

Comment: Yea I forgot about that. Thanks for your help I will stick with your solution because its easier for me to integrate into what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes SQL Server 2005 or later version.

The idea is first to join `Trade` and `price_details` filtering out prices whose times are greater than the corresponding trades' times:

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.Trade t
  INNER JOIN dbo.price_details pr ON pr.exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker
```

The above will get you a row set where every trade has got all prices up to the time of the trade. Now just rank the prices and get the latest one:

```
WITH trade_prices AS (
  SELECT
    t.*,                -- actually you might want to review the list
    pr.price_set_date,  -- of columns being pulled from the two tables
    pr.buy_price,
    pr.sell_price,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.trade_id ORDER BY pr.price_set_date DESC)
  FROM dbo.Trade t
    INNER JOIN dbo.price_details pr ON pr.exch_ticker = t.exch_ticker
)
SELECT *
FROM trade_prices
WHERE rnk = 1
```

To incorporate this into your view, you will only need to:

1) add the `trade_prices` CTE,

2) replace two joins, to `Trade` and to `price_details`, with a join to `trade_prices`,

3) add the `trade_prices.rnk = 1` condition to the `WHERE` clause.

Of course, the `trader` table will now be joined to `trade_prices` instead of to `Trade`. And you will also need to change the table aliases `pr` and `t` in the view's select list to the one you choose to assign to `trade_prices`.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I will look at your solution as well to see if I find it more useful.